# Python: finding uid/gid for a given username/groupname (for os.chown)

Tags: python

What's a good way to find the uid/gid for a given username or groupname using Python? I need to set file ownership with os.chown and need the integer ids instead of the alphabetic.

[Quick note]: getpwnam works great but is not available on windows, so here's some code that creates stubs to allow you to run the same code on windows and unix.

```
try:
    from pwd import getpwnam
except:
    getpwnam = lambda x: (0,0,0)
    os.chown = lambda x, y, z: True
    os.chmod = lambda x, y: True
    os.fchown = os.chown
    os.fchmod = os.chmod
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python script to list users and groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421618/python-script-to-list-users-and-groups)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use the [`pwd`](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html) and [`grp`](http://docs.python.org/library/grp.html) modules:

```
from pwd import getpwnam  

print getpwnam('someuser')[2]
# or
print getpwnam('someuser').pw_uid
print grp.getgrnam('somegroup')[2]
```

Comment: grp is not defined...

Comment: This is mostly correct, here's a more thorough example using the python3 repl.

```
user@host:/var/tmp# python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pwd import getpwnam
>>> from grp import getgrnam
>>> getpwnam('user_name').pw_uid
1000
>>> getgrnam('group_name').gr_gid
1000
```

Where the `user_name` and `group_name` are placeholders for the names you want the ids for.

Comment: from grp import getgrnam

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to help clarify previous examples.

Use the `pwd` and `grp` modules.

```
from pwd import getpwnam
from grp import getgrnam
```

Within your code where the need is to extract the UIDs for `name` and `group`, you will use the following.

> Note: The parameters `user_name` and `group_name` are placeholders. Replace them with the actual names you're targeting.

```
getpwnam('user_name').pw_uid # Returns UID only
getgrnam('group_name').gr_gid # Returns GID only
```

> Note: `getgrnam` returns a class called `grp.struct_group` and `getpwnam` returns a class called `pwd.struct_passwd`. As previously mentioned, you can access the ids from that struct via an index (i.e. `getpwnam('user_name')[2]`) or through dot notation as shown in the example(s) above.