# How to change the user and group permissions for a directory, by name?

Tags: python, operating-system, chown

[os.chown](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chown) is exactly what I want, but I want to specify the user and group by name, not ID (I don't know what they are). How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: finding uid/gid for a given username/groupname (for os.chown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826082/python-finding-uid-gid-for-a-given-username-groupname-for-os-chown)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
import pwd
import grp
import os

uid = pwd.getpwnam("nobody").pw_uid
gid = grp.getgrnam("nogroup").gr_gid
path = '/tmp/f.txt'
os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

Comment: Can I set without providing a `gid`?

Comment: Yes, just pass -1 for the ID you want to ignore as per the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chown)

Answer (score 58):

Since Python 3.3
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/shutil.html#shutil.chown

```
import shutil
shutil.chown(path, user=None, group=None)
```

Change owner user and/or group of the given path.

user can be a system user name or a uid; 
the same applies to group.

At least one argument is required.

Availability: Unix.

Answer (score 5):

Since the shutil version supports group being optional, I copy and pasted the code to my Python2 project.

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/shutil.py#l1010

```
def chown(path, user=None, group=None):
    """Change owner user and group of the given path.

    user and group can be the uid/gid or the user/group names, and in that case,
    they are converted to their respective uid/gid.
    """

    if user is None and group is None:
        raise ValueError("user and/or group must be set")

    _user = user
    _group = group

    # -1 means don't change it
    if user is None:
        _user = -1
    # user can either be an int (the uid) or a string (the system username)
    elif isinstance(user, basestring):
        _user = _get_uid(user)
        if _user is None:
            raise LookupError("no such user: {!r}".format(user))

    if group is None:
        _group = -1
    elif not isinstance(group, int):
        _group = _get_gid(group)
        if _group is None:
            raise LookupError("no such group: {!r}".format(group))

    os.chown(path, _user, _group)
```

Comment: You should check against basestr no?

Answer (score -3):

You can use `id -u wong2` to get the uid of a user
You can do this with python:

```
import os 
def getUidByUname(uname):
    return os.popen("id -u %s" % uname).read().strip()
```

Then use the id to `os.chown`