# How to set a files owner in python?

Tags: python, file-permissions

Firstly is it possible to set a file's owner with python?
And if so how do you set a file's owner with python?

Comment: Presumably this is on a UNIX (like) operating system? Also, http://whathaveyoutried.com.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

The uid and gid can be retrieved from a string by

```
import pwd
import grp
import os

uid = pwd.getpwnam("nobody").pw_uid
gid = grp.getgrnam("nogroup").gr_gid
```

Reference: [How to change the user and group permissions for a directory, by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994840/how-to-change-the-user-and-group-permissions-for-a-directory-by-name)

Comment: os.chown only available on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but might help in the future for those who wish to set files owner in windows.

*I have yet to find a pure 'pythonic' method, this is the alternative:

Windows provides the following takeown.exe utility which we will take advantage of:

takeown /f folder_path /r /d Y ('r' for recursively take ownership on all files and folders in the tree and 'd' for default input parameter that will allow to take ownership on all files\folders). 
further documentation : [msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown#remarks)

Code sample:

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_output
check_output(["takeown", "/f", path_, "/r", "/d", "Y"], stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: takeown /d /y only works for English.  If you're running German, etc, the 'Y' option isn't correct (J in German, etc).  Not a super reliable way to do this.