# Granting Access Permission to a file/folder to a specific user in python

Tags: python, user-permissions

I want to automate the 'Granting Access Permission to a file/folder to a specific user' using python. Please help me which command i need to use.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
KVJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the user and group permissions for a directory, by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994840/how-to-change-the-user-and-group-permissions-for-a-directory-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to change permissions on a UNIX platform.

```
import subprocess
import shlex

subprocess.call(shlex.split("chgrp -R groupname foldername"))
```

The `-R` flag changes the group permissions recursively for a given folder.