# How To Change Permission For Folder / Directory in Windows Using Python

Tags: python, windows, permissions, shutil

I see a lot of answers, such as: [How to change the user and group permissions for a directory, by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994840/how-to-change-the-user-and-group-permissions-for-a-directory-by-name) but they all involve using `os.chown()` which requires a userid number and groupid number.  I haven't figured out how to filter out questions that use that method since it doesn't work for me.

I'm on a Windows platform, NOT UNIX, so I don't have access to `import pwd` and `import grp` to get the ID numbers.

Basically, I used Python to copy a folder, via:

```
shutil.copytree(_dir + mostRecentFile, _dir + mostRecentFile + " - Copy")
```

But when I right click on the folder and go to Properties -> Security, I notice that one of the 'Group or user names' is missing.  When I copy it manually, that 'Group or user names' is NOT missing.  How do I add that 'Group or user names' via python?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Python's [system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) call to execute the Windows commands to set the user and group names

Comment: Ok let me try that, thanks