# user_id of a specific user on some AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, userid

I want to get the user_id of a specific user on an AWS instance. I can get this information from /etc/passwd file. but i want to get this information in a python script. Is there any way to get this information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script to list users and groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421618/python-script-to-list-users-and-groups)

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I want to get this info for some aws instances, not for my local machine.

Comment: you can run this script on the EC2 instance, do you need to run it locally pinging the EC2 instance ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri  i need user_id for more than one instances, how can i get the info for all from my local machine?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri is the any way using boto to get user_id for instances.

Comment: If you need to get the user account on the EC2 instances, boto will not help and you'll need the script I referenced - If you need the IAM account, yes you'll use boto