# Choose specific user from list using `os.system()`

Tags: python, list, debian

I need to create a menu screen in Python of all the users in the system, and after the system displays the list you choose the user you want and then another menu should pop-up.

So far I have:

```
os.system("cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd")    
chose = str(raw_input("Select user from this list > "))
```

How can I make the second list appear after I choose a user?

Comment: It depend on what you are using.

Comment: Do you mean, are you trying to get the output of `os.system()`? If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on) would be helpful.

Comment: I mean that after lets say the list of users I have is  root,  user1, user2 etc.. after I choose lets say user2 a new list of options needs to pop up with new commands like show user groups or show user id etc...

Comment: Why don't you just parse `/etc/passwd` in Python?

Comment: [Python script to list users and groups](http://stackoverflow.com/q/421618/3821804)

Comment: Which `second list`?

Comment: The command should look like this:
1) List of all users
When I choose this list another list pops up:
1)user1 2)user2 and so on, if I pick user 1 a new list of options should appears like 1)show user groups 2) show user id and so on
and I don't know how to write a command that will connect me between the user list to the user id and groups options list.

p.s I'm on debian os writing in python for those who asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pwd` and `grp` modules.
*We use `grp` to get user group.*

```
import pwd, grp

user = ''
users = pwd.getpwall()
i=0
for p in users:
    print str(i) + ')' + str(p[0])
    i+=1


chose = int(raw_input("Select user from this list > "))
user = users[chose]
print
print '1) show user groups \n2) show user id'
print 
chose = int(raw_input("Your choice > "))

if chose == 1:
    print grp.getgrgid(user.pw_gid).gr_name
else:
    print user.pw_uid
```

Comment: Thanks that solved half of my problem now I only need to figure out how to tell the program to open another list in relation to the user I chose. like:
1) show user groups
2)show user id
3)show user alias 
and so on