# How to get all Windows/Linux user and not only current user with python

Tags: python, getpass

I know how to get the current user using os or getpass.getuser(), but is there a way to get a list of all user and not only the current one? Read os and getpass documentations but i didn't thing anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421618/python-script-to-list-users-and-groups

Answer (score 1):

This is OS-specific.

In Linux, see [Python script to list users and groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421618/python-script-to-list-users-and-groups).

In Windows:

- via WMI

  - parse the output of [`wmic UserAccount get Name`](https://superuser.com/questions/608931/list-all-user-accounts-on-a-windows-system-via-command-line/608973#608973), or
  - make the same call with the [`wmi` module](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/):

    ```
    import wmi
    w=wmi.WMI()
    # The argument (field filter) is only really needed if browsing a large domain
    # as per the warning at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount
    # Included it for the sake of completeness
    for u in w.Win32_UserAccount(["Name"]): #Net
        print u.Name
    del u
    ```
- via the [`NetUserEnum` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum)

  - parse the output of `net user`, or
  - make the same call with [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/):

    ```
    import win32net, win32netcon
    names=[]; resumeHandle=0
    while True:
        data,_,resumeHandle=win32net.NetUserEnum(None,0,
                win32netcon.FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT,resumeHandle)
        names.extend(e["name"] for e in data)
        if not resumeHandle: break
    del data,resumeHandle
    print names
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas for methods that are Windows-specific:

```py
from pathlib import Path
users = [x.name for x in Path(r'C:\Users').glob('*') if x.name not in ['Default', 'Default User', 'Public', 'All Users'] and x.is_dir()]
print(users)
```

*Paths in C:\Users*

```py
import os
os.system('net user > users.txt')
users = Path('./users.txt').read_text()
print(users)
```

*Output from [net user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771865(v=ws.11))*

Comment: The 1st one is defective: https://superuser.com/questions/608931/list-all-user-accounts-on-a-windows-system-via-command-line

Comment: `net user` output is not the raw list and will have to be parsed (with possible problems if names have unusual and/or national characters).