# Portable way of checking if *some* user exists in either Linux or Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, portability

I need to check if a user exists in either Linux or Windows, using Python 3 (3.7 right now for reasons unrelated).

No, `pwd` doesn't work on Windows.

No, `getpass` only returns current username, while I need to check *any* username.

Comment: for linux, check if `/home/username` folder exist. For Windows check if `c:\Users\username` exist. You can know if you are on windows or linux using `platform.system()`, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110362/how-can-i-find-the-current-os-in-python

Comment: User management is inherently OS-specific, what makes you think there is a portable solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all Windows/Linux user and not only current user with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300490/how-to-get-all-windows-linux-user-and-not-only-current-user-with-python)

Answer (score -1):

as far as i know, there is no universal command for both distros, but you can check the env in your script

```
import os
if os.name [...]
```

or

```
import platform
my_os = platform.system()
```

based on this you can create different functions for both os.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. It doesn;t check if a certain user exist

Comment: only if you don't understand..


I need to check if a user exists in either Linux or Windows, using Python 3 (3.7 right now for reasons unrelated).

No, pwd doesn't work on Windows.

No, getpass only returns current username, while I need to check any username.

So he was going to use a universal method which doesn't exist. 
For windows you can go with : Get-LocalUser
and on linux awk -F: '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd or less /etc/passwd

Comment: @yosh1da Why not transform your comment into full blown answer? I'd accept it.